# CUFFT result ordering and operations on results (symmetric frequency) CUDA (physics simulation)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, cuda, fftw

I am currently battling a problem with CUDA and 2D indexing - I think.

I have a physics simulation written in C++ using FFTW which I want
to port to CUDA to check out the feasibility of CUDA in this field.

Program description:
The Problem is quantum mechanical and I am using the [split-operator method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-step_method).
Thus I have to transform x<->k space (or time <-> freq if you choose) quite often.
In each space I have to multiply the (complex) data with other complex numbers.
The main loop of my program is shown below in C++ with FFTW.

```
fftw_execute(DFTPlan);
    double dkX = 2.0*M_PI/Par.xMax;
    double dkY = 2.0*M_PI/Par.yMax;


    //intermediate steps
    for (uint k(1); k < Par.Nsteps-1; ++k) {
        //apply momentum operator - tricky part
        for (uint itX(0); itX < Par.Nx / 2; ++itX) {
            for (uint itY(0); itY < Par.Ny / 2; ++itY) {
                //1st quadrant
                tmpRe = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + (Par.Nx - 1 - itX)][0];
                tmpIm = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + (Par.Nx - 1 - itX)][1];
                MomentumNorm = SQU((itX + 1) * dkX) + SQU((itY + 1) * dkY);
          MomentumNorm /= 2.0;
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + (Par.Nx - 1 - itX)][0] = tmpRe * cos( -dt *MomentumNorm ) - tmpIm*sin(-dt*MomentumNorm);
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + (Par.Nx - 1 - itX)][1] = tmpRe * sin( -dt *MomentumNorm ) + tmpIm*cos(-dt*MomentumNorm);

                //2nd quadrant
                tmpRe = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + itX][0];
                tmpIm = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + itX][1];
                MomentumNorm = SQU(itX * dkX) + SQU((itY + 1) * dkY);
          MomentumNorm /= 2.0;
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + itX][0] = tmpRe * cos( -dt *MomentumNorm ) - tmpIm*sin(-dt*MomentumNorm);
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*(Par.Ny - 1 -itY) + itX][1] = tmpRe * sin( -dt *MomentumNorm ) + tmpIm*cos(-dt*MomentumNorm);
                //3rd quadrant
                tmpRe = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + itX][0];
                tmpIm = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + itX][1];
                MomentumNorm = SQU(itX * dkX) + SQU(itY * dkY);
          MomentumNorm /= 2.0;
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + itX][0] = tmpRe * cos( -dt *MomentumNorm ) - tmpIm*sin(-dt*MomentumNorm);
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + itX][1] = tmpRe * sin( -dt *MomentumNorm ) + tmpIm*cos(-dt*MomentumNorm);
                //4th quadrant
                tmpRe = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + (Par.Nx-1-itX)][0];
                tmpIm = psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + (Par.Nx-1-itX)][1];
                MomentumNorm = SQU((itX + 1) * dkX) + SQU(itY * dkY);
          MomentumNorm /= 2.0;
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + (Par.Nx-1-itX)][0] = tmpRe * cos( -dt *MomentumNorm ) - tmpIm*sin(-dt*MomentumNorm);
                psiMomSpace[Par.Nx*itY + (Par.Nx-1-itX)][1] = tmpRe * sin( -dt *MomentumNorm ) + tmpIm*cos(-dt*MomentumNorm);
            }
        }
        //inverse FFT
        fftw_execute(IDFTPlan);
        //rescale
        for (uint j(0); j < Par.Nx * Par.Ny; ++j) {
            psiPosSpace[j][0] /= scalingFactor;
            psiPosSpace[j][1] /= scalingFactor;
        }
        if(k % 20 == 0){
        //plot ... omitted for brevity
        }
        //apply position operator
        for (uint j(0); j < Par.Nx * Par.Ny; ++j) {
            tmpRe = psiPosSpace[j][0];
            tmpIm = psiPosSpace[j][1];
            if ((x[j] == Par.xMin || x[j] == Par.xMax) || (y[j] == Par.yMin || y[j] == Par.yMax)) {
                psiPosSpace[j][0] = psiPosSpace[j][1] = 0.0;
                continue;
            }
            psiPosSpace[j][0] = tmpRe * cos(-V(x[j], y[j], 0.0) * dt) - tmpIm * sin(-V(x[j], y[j], 0.0) * dt);
            psiPosSpace[j][1] = tmpRe * sin(-V(x[j], y[j], 0.0) * dt) + tmpIm * cos(-V(x[j], y[j], 0.0) * dt);
        }
        //forward fft
        fftw_execute(DFTPlan);
    }
```

Here the part where I apply the momentum operator (p^2/2m, or p^2/2 in these units)
is what gives me headaches with CUDA. Due to the storage order for the k-Values 
(0, k_max in array positions[0,...N/2-1], -k_max, ..dk in positions[N/2,...,N-1]
 for a 1D array) I have just broken down the 2D domain into 4 parts and treat each one
individually. Essentially I need to compute for each array element an associated linear momentum ($k^2 = k_x^2+k_y^2$)
and apply $e^{-ik^2*dt/2}$ to that array element.

This works in FFTW, the simulation works as expected.
Now here is the kernel I wrote for use with CUDA

```
__global__ void kineticOperator(cuDoubleComplex* data, const double dkX, const double dkY, const double dt) {
    double tmpRe, tmpIm, momentumNorm;
    int kIdxX, kIdxY, gridSizeX, gridSizeY;
    gridSizeX = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    gridSizeY = gridDim.y * blockDim.y;

    if (blockIdx.x < gridDim.x / 2) {
        //quadrants 2 & 3
        if (blockIdx.y < gridDim.y / 2) {
            //quadrant 3
            kIdxX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            kIdxY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

            tmpRe = data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + kIdxX].x;
            tmpIm = data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + kIdxX].y;

            momentumNorm = SQU(kIdxX * dkX) + SQU(kIdxY * dkY);
            momentumNorm /= 2.0;
            data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + kIdxX].x = tmpRe * cos(-dt * momentumNorm) - tmpIm * sin(-dt * momentumNorm);
            data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + kIdxX].y = tmpRe * sin(-dt * momentumNorm) + tmpIm * cos(-dt * momentumNorm);
        } else {
            //quadrant 2
            kIdxX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            kIdxY = (blockIdx.y - gridDim.y / 2) * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

            tmpRe = data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + kIdxX].x;
            tmpIm = data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + kIdxX].y;
            momentumNorm = SQU(kIdxX * dkX) + SQU((kIdxY + 1) * dkY);
            momentumNorm /= 2.0;
            data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + kIdxX].x = tmpRe * cos(-dt * momentumNorm) - tmpIm * sin(-dt * momentumNorm);
            data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + kIdxX].y = tmpRe * sin(-dt * momentumNorm) + tmpIm * cos(-dt * momentumNorm);
        }

    } else {
        //quadrants 1 & 4
        if (blockIdx.y < gridDim.y / 2) {
            //quadrant 4
            kIdxX = (blockIdx.x - gridDim.x / 2) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            kIdxY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

            tmpRe = data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].x;
            tmpIm = data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].y;

            momentumNorm = SQU((kIdxX + 1) * dkX) + SQU(kIdxY * dkY);
            momentumNorm /= 2.0;
            data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].x = tmpRe * cos(-dt * momentumNorm) - tmpIm * sin(-dt * momentumNorm);
            data[gridSizeX * kIdxY + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].y = tmpRe * sin(-dt * momentumNorm) + tmpIm * cos(-dt * momentumNorm);
        } else {
            //quadrant 1
            kIdxX = (blockIdx.x - gridDim.x / 2) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            kIdxY = (blockIdx.y - gridDim.y / 2) * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

            tmpRe = data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].x;
            tmpIm = data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].y;

            momentumNorm = SQU((kIdxX + 1) * dkX) + SQU((kIdxY + 1) * dkY);
            momentumNorm /= 2.0;
            data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].x = tmpRe * cos(-dt * momentumNorm) - tmpIm * sin(-dt * momentumNorm);
            data[gridSizeX * (gridSizeY - (kIdxY + 1)) + (gridSizeX - (kIdxX + 1))].y = tmpRe * sin(-dt * momentumNorm) + tmpIm * cos(-dt * momentumNorm);
        }
    }
};
```

and it yields crap - A plot of the result after an IFFT and rescaling yields a uniform coloring of the whole domain.
Here's the part of the code where I call it:

```
for (uint k(1); k < Par.Nsteps - 1; ++k) {
        t = k*dt;
        //apply momentum operator
        cudaVerifyKernel((kineticOperator<<<gDim,bDim>>>(psiMomSpaceDev, dkX, dkY, dt)));
        //inverse FFT
        cudaVerify(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        if (cufftExecZ2Z(cuDFTPlan, psiMomSpaceDev, psiPosSpaceDev, CUFFT_INVERSE) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
            std::cerr << "CUFFT ERROR! Error executing inverse FFT." << std::endl;
            return (-1);
        }
        if (cudaThreadSynchronize() != cudaSuccess) {
            std::cout << "Failed to synchronize threads" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        //rescale
        cudaVerifyKernel((scalingKernel<<<gDim, bDim>>>(psiPosSpaceDev, scalingFactor)));
        if (k % 20 == 0) {
            //sync device, copy to host, plot.
        }

        //apply position operator
        cudaVerifyKernel((potentialOperator<<<gDim, bDim>>>(xDev, yDev, psiPosSpaceDev, t, dt)));
        //forward fft
        cudaVerify(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        if (cufftExecZ2Z(cuDFTPlan, psiPosSpaceDev, psiMomSpaceDev, CUFFT_FORWARD) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
            std::cerr << "CUFFT ERROR! Error executing forward FFT." << std::endl;
            return (-1);
        }
        if (cudaThreadSynchronize() != cudaSuccess) {
            std::cout << "Failed to synchronize threads" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

The array is of size 256x256 and using 16 threads per block per dimension I get 16 blocks
per dimension, thus a grid of 16 x 16 blocks with 16x16 threads per block.

Problem:
The results after applying the kinetic operator with CUDA are completely off and I just do not
see why. I have tried different ways of writing the kernel, but the result is still the same. For the FFT I am using

```
cufftPlan2d(&cuDFTPlan, Par.Nx, Par.Ny, CUFFT_Z2Z);
```

where in this case Par.Nx = Par.Ny = 256;

I hope somebody can point me to my error, this (and the limit of 1024 threads/block) has been
driving me mad since the day before yesterday.

Comment: Meta comment: This is a lot of code to throw at us and say, "Why doesn't this work?"  I realize that is your question (and quite a frustrating one!), but if you could isolate smaller and possibly more generic examples of unexpected behavior I think you would have a greater chance of receiving help.